# new line when user press enter in edit text in android

Tags: android

I am trying to create edit text in which when user presses enter it goes to new line and allow user to enter more text.

here is my design part

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/discussion"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="100dp"
                            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                            android:maxLines="5"
                            android:hint="Discussion outcome"
                            android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890 "/>

                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Here is my code, but the problem is cursor position is not going to the next line.  i tried `discussion.append("\n")` too but it didnt work

```
discussion= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.discussion);
        discussion.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {

                Log.e(TAG , "Key  Action "+keyEvent.getAction());

                if(keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){

                    String data =discussion.getText().toString();

                    discussion.setText(data+"\n");
                    Log.e(TAG , "Key "+keyEvent.getKeyCode());



                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should include the newline character `\n` in the allowed digits in your xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/discussion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:hint="Discussion outcome"
        android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890\n "/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Next, you don't need any key listeners if you do that.

Comment: What about other languages?

Comment: what about special characters?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<EditText
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:inputType="textMultiLine"
   android:ems="10"
   android:id="@+id/edt_address"
   android:hint="Shipping Address" />
```

hope it will help you

Comment: i tried this already from another stackoverflow thread but it didnt work , what i am trying to implement is when user press enter key cursor should go into next line.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20475011/13179254
Basically what you need to do:

Kotlin:

```kotlin
isSingleLine = false
```

Java:

```java
setSingleLine(false)
```

Xml:

```xml
android:singleLine="false"
```

Comment: {@deprecated This attribute is deprecated. Use <code>maxLines</code> instead to change
             the layout of a static text, and use the <code>textMultiLine</code> flag in the
             inputType attribute instead for editable text views (if both singleLine and inputType
             are supplied, the inputType flags will override the value of singleLine). } -->